# C++ OpenGL - How to make a 2D square move on screen?

Tags: c++, opengl

How do I make a 2D square move on the screen? I try to move it but it just stays there.

```
int x = 100;
int y = 100;
int width = 50;
int height = 50;

x += 1;

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(r, g, b);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glVertex2f(x + width, y);
    glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
    glVertex2f(x, y + height);
glEnd();
```

It all loads fine, it draws the square and everything, but it just doesn't move the square, I'm using SDL to draw the window incase you want to know.

Comment: Is the whole code you pasted in one function? Then it cannot work, since you need to keep the value of `x` between draws. If not, we need some more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL expects you to send relative coordinates between 0 and 1. Moreover, you create new variables every frame, so they can't really be incremented along all frames.

```
// box parameters in pixels
int boxleft = 100,
    boxbottom = 100;
int boxwidth = 50,
    boxheight = 50;

// window dimensions
int screenwidth = 1920,
    screenheight = 1080;

for(;;)
{
    // clear last frame
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // calculate screen space coordinates
    float left   = (float)boxleft / screenwidth,
          right  = left + (float)boxwidth / screenwidth,
          bottom = (float)boxbottom / screenheight,
          top    = bottom + (float)boxheight / screenheight;

    // draw the box
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(r, g, b);
        glVertex2f(left,  top);
        glVertex2f(right, top);
        glVertex2f(right, bottom);
        glVertex2f(left,  bottom);
    glEnd();

    // shift box for next frame
    boxleft++;
}
```

Update: Okay, you say the square draws fine with your coordinates, so you might not change that. But defining the variables outside your draw loop is essential. Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: OKay, I see. The reason my square drew fine is because I used glOrtho. So yeah. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's all one function, the issue is that the begining of the function is constantly resetting your value for x to 100. Move your variable definitions out of the function. As an example:

```
int x = 100;
int y = 100;
int width = 50;
int height = 50;

function drawSquare()
{    
    x += 1;

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(r, g, b);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        glVertex2f(x + width, y);
        glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
        glVertex2f(x, y + height);
    glEnd();
}
```

Each time you call that function, the square will have x incremented by one and so will move progressively over.

Comment: I think just making the variable static is easier.

Comment: Either would work. I'm just not personally a fan of static variables in functions. I find more often then not those variables need to be modified other places.

Comment: @Xonar that really depends on the language, if the language was Java, then I would probably use static variables. But as the question is tagged C++ then, well, why would you use static variables, while global scope variables do just fine.

Comment: @Vallentin to not pollute your global scope